# Xamarin.Forms 2 DatePickers Don't allow end date to be before start date

Tags: datetime, datepicker, inotifypropertychanged, xamarin.forms

I have two datepickers bound to an object inheriting from INotifyPropertyChanged - here is the code for the DateTime properties

```cs
private DateTime _startDate;

public DateTime StartDate
{
    get { return _startDate; }
    set
    {
        if (DateTime.Compare(value, _startDate) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        _startDate = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

//public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

private DateTime _endDate;
public DateTime EndDate
{
    get { return _endDate; }
    set
    {

        if (DateTime.Compare(value, _endDate) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        _endDate = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

in the forms page I have this

```cs
        DatePicker startDate = new DatePicker
        {
            BindingContext = uCoSafe,
            Format = "D"
        };
        startDate.SetBinding(DatePicker.DateProperty, new Binding("StartDate", BindingMode.OneWayToSource));

        startDate.PropertyChanged +=(sender, e) =>
            {
                 uCoSafe.EndDate = uCoSafe.StartDate.AddDays(1);

            };
        MyCoLabel endDateLbl = new MyCoLabel(1, "End Date");
        DatePicker endDate = new DatePicker
        {
            BindingContext = uCoSafe,
            Format = "D"
        };
        endDate.SetBinding(DatePicker.DateProperty, new Binding("StartDate", BindingMode.TwoWay));
```

This all works fine. If I change the start date then the end date is updated.

I also want it, if the end date is changed manually then it can't be set before the start date.

i tried this

```cs
endDate.PropertyChanged +=  (sender, e) =>
{
    if (uCoSafe.EndDate.Date <= uCoSafe.StartDate.Date)
    {
        uCoSafe.EndDate = uCoSafe.StartDate.AddDays(1);
        DisplayAlert("End Date Error", "End date cannot be earlier than the start date, please try again", "OK");
     }

}
```

But it only triggers when the startDate is changed (when I don't want the message) but not when the datepicker for endDate is manually changed.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding for `endDate` looks wrong. You wrote:

```
endDate.SetBinding(DatePicker.DateProperty, new Binding("StartDate", BindingMode.TwoWay));
```

And you probably meant:

```
endDate.SetBinding(DatePicker.DateProperty, new Binding("EndDate", BindingMode.TwoWay));
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

And this should get you back on the track.

Now, what *I* would do in this case, instead of displaying an alert in case of error, is just prevent the user to make such error, by Binding the `MinimumDateProperty` of the `endDate` to the `uCoSafe.StartDate`. That will probably make a better user experience at the end, still IMHO.

Comment: Doh!!! the pitfalls of copy and paste! Thankyou for picking that up and also thanks for the MinimumDateProperty suggestion, it works perfectly

Comment: Keep in mind that if the date is already set, updating MinimumDate won't "fix" the date to take that into account. You still have to validate on submit.

Comment: @AnthonyMills setting the `MinimumDate` on the picker **will** update the `Date` property to make sure `MinimumDate` <= `Date` <= `MaximumDate`

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix I have a page with the `MinimumDate` of the second control bound as the `Date` of the first. I assure you I can set the first control to be after the second, and the second will not update. But perhaps the rules are different for binding than setting values outright?